# SQL Trigger with existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a SQL problem with a trigger that I made that I can't solve, I want to make a bad word filter for my database. I made this trigger that works fine:

```
USE dbi353348
GO 

Create TRIGGER trChangeAbusiveWordzondertable
ON Post
AFTER INSERT
AS

    DECLARE @Posttekst varchar(300);
    DECLARE @AccountID int;
    DECLARE @PostID int;
    SELECT @Posttekst=i.Post FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @AccountID=i.Account_ID FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @PostID=i.Post_ID FROM inserted i;
BEGIN

DECLARE @AbusiveWords TABLE(ID INT,Word VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @AbusiveWords (ID,Word) values (1,'kanker'),(2,'tyfus'),(3,'tering'),(4,'kut'),(5,'lul'),(6,'eikel'),(7,'klootzak'),(8,'hoer'),(9,'flikker'),(10,'mongool'),(11,'slet'),(12,'bitch');

UPDATE @AbusiveWords
SET @Posttekst=REPLACE(@Posttekst,Word,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Word,'A','#'),'E','%'),'I','$'),'O','*'),'U','@')) 

UPDATE Post
SET Post = @Posttekst
WHERE Post_ID = @PostID

END
```

Now I want to make it so the bad words get chosen from an existing table, 'Abusivewords' from my database. This trigger gets created but doesn't change anything:

```
Use dbi353348
GO 

Create TRIGGER trChangeAbusiveWord
ON Post
AFTER INSERT
AS

    DECLARE @Posttekst varchar(300);
    DECLARE @AccountID int;
    DECLARE @PostID int;
    SELECT @Posttekst=i.Post FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @AccountID=i.Account_ID FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @PostID=i.Post_ID FROM inserted i;
BEGIN


UPDATE AbusiveWords
SET @Posttekst=REPLACE(@Posttekst,Word,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Word,'A','#'),'E','%'),'I','$'),'O','*'),'U','@')) 

UPDATE Post
SET Post = @Posttekst
WHERE Post_ID = @PostID

END
```

I recon that the mistake is somewhere in the update statement.

Comment: should be updating WORD not a variable @postteskt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue on updating @Posttekst where should be the field from AbusiveWords

```
UPDATE AbusiveWords
SET WORD=REPLACE(@Posttekst,Word,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Word,'A','#'),'E','%'),'I','$'),'O','*'),'U','@'))
```

Comment: that strangly changes all the word in the AbusiveWords table into the inserted word and does not change the bad word in the other Post table. Am I missing something here?

Comment: that is just to highlight the updating issue. so question, why you need to update the AbusiveWords table?

Comment: I need to change some characters in the bad words that are inserted so I can later change them in the other table, 'Post' with the update. With a temporary table I can do this easily but then I cannot add words to the bad words filter.  I think this is the wrong approach